# WordPress Menu adds an unwanted slash before anchor

Tags: menus, jquery

I need a WordPress menu item to link to a custom url like the following:

```
http://www.example.com/my-page#my-anchor
```

Yet, WordPress adds a slash before the hash sign and reformats the custom link to

```
http://www.example.com/my-page/#my-anchor
```

thus invalidating the jQuery call I need.

Comment: Sounds like your jQuery isn't very flexible, if this was me I would probably edit the JS before trying to make WP not add the trailing slash

Comment: yeah show us your jQuery and we can maybe help fix that instead

Comment: Thanks very much. the Jquery plugin I'm using is called "Easy responsive tabs to Accordion"

https://webthemez.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html

What I need to do is linking directly to a specified tab, whence the need to have a nav menu link of the type  "http://www.example.com/my-page#my-anchor" as per above, where no slash is added in front of the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You can likely change that by removing the slash from the end of the permalink structure on `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` & you should be good to go.

[image]

But as [Krzysiek Dróżdż](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/34172/krzysiek-dr%c3%b3%c5%bcd%c5%bc) has said: It shouldn't make a difference in the execution of javaScript & trailing slashes are a best-practaice.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to end URLs with slashes. It also shouldn't be any problem at all.

It makes no difference for JS. With or without that slash, the `window.location.hash` will have the same value.

So if only the JS library you use is written correctly, then the slash won't change anything. And if it does - you should report it as a bug to the author of that library.

Comment: It sounds like the plugin might be using `location.href` instead of say `location.origin`.

Comment: https://github.com/samsono/Easy-Responsive-Tabs-to-Accordion/blob/master/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js  I don't see any location.href anywhere. It's location.hash only...

Comment: You're right, doesn't seem like there's any reason for it to have a problem with the trailing slash then. Must be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'd rather stay with trailing slash and try to debug the real problem...

Comment: I'm guessing it's a jQuery conflict. The repo contains versions 1.9.1 & 1.6.3. I had assumed the question was a problem with a WordPress plugin... But I'm guessing it's a combination of many problems, least of which being inexperience on OP's part.